# Personal Access Token not working on Linux

Tags: linux, git, github, token

I am using Git on Linux.
I followed [this](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) to create a Personal Access Token but forgot to save it.
Therefore, when I was asked to enter the "password" again, I deleted the old PAT and created a new PAT. For some reason, the new token is rejected and I get

`fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/username/***.git/'`

When I look at the tokens page on github, this token says it was never used. What might be the issue here?

Comment: I have edited my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue might be with your current credential helper.

Type `git config credential.helper` to see which one is used.

Type:

```
printf "protocol=https\nhost=github.com"|git-credential-xxx erase
```

(Replace `xxx` by the credential helper name from the first command output)

That will clear out the cached credentials for `https://github.com`.

Then try again a `git push`, and see if it asks you for your credentials: enter your new PAT as password.

If you don't have a credential helper, I suggest installing [`microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core`](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core) (there is a [Linux package](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core#linux)).
[Add a credential store](https://github.com/microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-Core/blob/main/docs/linuxcredstores.md#credential-stores-on-linux), and you are set.

---

After [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236379/discussion-between-vonc-and-user15988):

- there was no credential helper
- this is a personnal account (not a technical service one, used by multiple users)
- the issue was with pasting the token

I would therefore use a store credential caching:

```
git config --global credential.helper 'store --file /home/<user>/.my-credentials
```

Then:

```
git ls-remote https://github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

That will trigger the prompt for your username and token.

Edit `/home/<user>/.my-credentials` and make sure the right token is in it.

---

Alternatively,

```
git config --global credential.helper 'store --file /home/<user>/.my-credentials'
```

and then:

```
git ls-remote https://<user>:<token>@github.com/<user>/<repo>
```

has worked.

Comment: @user15988 So you mean you enter your GitHub username and new PAT manually each time you `git push`?

Comment: yes. it's my first time using PAT. I plan to store it next time.

Comment: @user15988 Did you create that PAT with the repo scope?

Comment: I added checks on "repo" and "write:packages".

Comment: @user15988 Did you create it 2 weeks ago, with a 7-days expiration? ;)

Comment: I created it a few hours ago with 30-day expiration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236379/discussion-between-vonc-and-user15988).

Answer (score -1):

I had to delete my token and create a new one and it worked for me